How to Convert an HTML Template into a WordPress Theme
I have a directory containing files for my website, including PHP and HTML files. I want to convert this into a WordPress website and upload my existing HTML template to use it as a WordPress theme.
What steps should I follow to turn my HTML template into a WordPress theme? Are there specific files or structure I need to create for WordPress compatibility? Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

you can find the official documentation here : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/

Hi, there are many tutorials and other resources on the internet for creating Wordpress themes. Asking for tutorials is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you get stuck with a specific problem while creating your theme then we'll be able to help.
